# compute the inverse of cumulative distribution function

Tags: python, distributions, scipy

I would like to estimate **the inverse of cumulative distribution function** for a quantity namely $C$ which is related to two other parameters, $M$ and $z$ with the following equation $$C=\frac{9.59}{1+z}\Big(\frac{10^{M}}{10^{14}}\Big)^{-0.102}$$  which the probability of $C$ is estimated by$$p(\log C)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\Big[-\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{\log C-\langle \log C\rangle}{\sigma}\Big)^2\Big]$$ here $\langle \log C\rangle$ is calculated via the first equation and for a given $M$ the dispersion $\sigma$ is equal to 0.09 for $M<15$ and 0.06 for $M\ge15$.
I would appreciate for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description $\log C\sim N(\langle\log C\rangle,\sigma^2)$, so $C$ has log-normal distribution with mean $\langle\log C\rangle$ and variance $\sigma^2$. That is, $$F(c)=\frac{1}{2}\left[1+\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{\log c-\langle\log C\rangle}{\sigma\sqrt2}\right)\right].$$ Thus, $$F^{-1}(c)=\exp\left(\sigma\sqrt2\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(2c-1)+\langle\log C\rangle\right).$$ Unfortunately $\mathrm{erf}$ and $\mathrm{erf}^{-1}$ don't have elmentary form but they are already implemented or can be easily implemented in tools like `Matlab` or `R`.

Comment: `scipy.stats.lognorm.ppf` also implement this but in an uncommon, standard location-scale distribution parameterization.